# Why is the (signed) cast necessary only sometimes to represent the minimum integer (32 bit system)?

Tags: c

I recently found this code:

```c
    for (i = 0; i < k; i ++) {
        b[i] = 0x80000000;  // min integer
        s[i] = 0;
    }
```

the above is part of this program:

```c
int _max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
int all_profits(int* prices, int pricesSize) {
    int i, d, p;

    p = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < pricesSize; i ++) {
        d = prices[i] - prices[i - 1];
        p = d > 0 ? p + d : p;  // get it as long as it is a profit!
    }

    return p;
}
int maxProfit(int k, int* prices, int pricesSize) {
    int *b, *s, *buff, i, j, p;

    if (pricesSize < 2) return 0;

    if (k >= pricesSize / 2) return all_profits(prices, pricesSize);

    buff = malloc((2 * k + 1) * sizeof(int));
    //assert(buff);
    b = &buff[0];
    s = &buff[k];

    for (i = 0; i < k; i ++) {
        b[i] = 0x80000000;  // min integer
        s[i] = 0;
    }
    s[k] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < pricesSize; i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {
            // profit on buy is current buy or last sale minus today's price
            b[j]     = _max(b[j],     s[j] - prices[i]);
            // profit on sale is current sale or last buy plus today's price
            s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);
        }
    }

    p = s[k];

    free(buff);

    return p;
}
```

where 0x80000000 really is treated as the minimum integer.

But then the same author does this in another problem to prevent integer overflow:

```c
int reverse(int x) {
    int d, k = 0;
    // 2147483647
    //-2147483648
    while (x) {
        d = x % 10;
        if ((x > 0 && k > (0x7fffffff - d) / 10) ||
            (x < 0 && k < ((signed)0x80000000 - d) / 10)) {
            return 0;   // overflow
        }
        k = k * 10 + d;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return k; //(int)k == k ? (int)k : 0;
}
```

(the above program reverses an integer.)

Here, the minimum is (signed)0x80000000. This hexadecimal is basically -2^31 from my understanding, the (signed) represents the minus sign.

The same author does this, so there must be a reason to it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: How are all the referenced variables defined?

Comment: @dbush put in the full code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0x80000000` is of course hexadecimal for the number 2,147,483,648, and this is the value it has in source code.

When `int` is 32 bits, it cannot represent 2,147,483,468, so `0x80000000` cannot be an `int` value. The C standard says that, instead of `int`, the type of `0x80000000` is `unsigned int`. (This is different for constants written in hexadecimal than in decimal. For `2147483648`, the type would be `long int` instead of `unsigned int`—a decimal constant is the first signed integer type it fits in, starting with `int`, but a hexadecimal constant is the first integer type it fits in, either signed or unsigned.)

So, in `b[i] = 0x80000000;`, we are assigning an `unsigned int` to an `int`. Assignment converts the value on the right to the type on the left. However, the value on the right cannot be represented in an `int`. In this case, the C standard says the result is implementation-defined. The binary value for `0x80000000` is of course 10000000000000000000000000000000. In the two’s complement system for representing signed 32-bit integers, the bit pattern for the smallest representable value, −2<sup>31</sup>, is also 10000000000000000000000000000000. Thus, the author of this code is relying on the conversion to produce the `int` value that has the same bit pattern as the unsigned value `0x80000000`.

As this is not guaranteed by the C standard, this code is not portable. The author might better have used `INT_MIN` instead of `0x80000000` or simply `(-2147483647-1)`.

In `((signed)0x80000000 - d) / 10`, consider what would happen if we instead wrote `(0x80000000 - d) / 10)`. Since `0x80000000` is an `unsigned int`, the subtraction would be evaluated by converting `d` to an `unsigned int` and dividing by 10. For example, if `d` were `−1`, it would be converted to `0xFFFFFFFF` (because conversion to `unsigned int` is defined by the C standard to wrap), and `0x80000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF` would produce `0x80000001`, which is 2,147,483,649, and division by 10 would produce 214,748,364. However, since the author cast to `signed`, meaning `signed int` or `int`, the `(signed)0x80000000` evaluates to an `int` value of −2,147,483,648, and the subtraction is evaluated with `int` arithmetic. Then we have `-2147483648 - -1`, which produces −2,147,483,647, and division by 10 produces −214,748,364.

So, in the assignment, implicit conversion produces the result the author desires (relying on implementation-defined behavior). In the arithmetic expression, there is no implicit conversion, so the author had to insert one explicitly. This is bad design for several reasons:

- It needlessly relies on implementation-defined behavior.
- It uses subtleties of C semantics that can easily go wrong when somebody modifies the expressions or writes new ones that attempt to use `0x80000000` as if it were the minimum `int` value.
- It does not document what it is doing or why.

Comment: What is "implementation-defined"? Is this referring to the implementation of the author's code, or the built-in C implementation that we can't easily see? And also, instead of using things like 0x80000000, we should use INT_MAX for portability, right? Why is (-2147483647-1)  good? Why not (-2147483645-3)? Why is this special?

Comment: @herophant: I have corrected that to “implementation-defined,” the official term used in the C standard. In the context of the C standard, an *implementation* is the software in a particular environment that translates C programs and supports their execution, largely a C compiler and associated libraries. *Implementation-defined* means the behavior may vary between different implementations, and each implementation is required to document it.

Comment: @herophant: For portability, one should use `INT_MIN` (not `INT_MAX`) if one wants the minimum `int` value, whatever it is. If one wants −2,147,483,648 regardless of whether it is the minimum `int` value or not, one should use `-2147483648`. If one wants the minimum `int` value in an implementation where that is −2,147,483,648 but cannot use `INT_MIN` for some reason, then `(-2147483647-1)` provides that value as an `int` type (whereas `-2147483648` would be a `long int` type, which one might be avoiding). `(-2147483647-3)` would be wrong because it does not have the desired value.

Comment: @herophant: Note that `-2147483648` is a `long int` (when `int` is two’s complement 32-bit) because the actual constant is `2147483648`, and `-2147483648` is an expression in which `-` is applied to that constant. Since `2147483648` is too big for an `int`, it is a `long int`, and then `-2147483648` is a `long int` even though its value fits in an `int`. Hence the use of `(-2147483647-1)` to work around that quirk and keep the arithmetic in `int`.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume a compiler with 32 bit `int`, the constant `0x80000000` is out of range for that type. Therefore, it gets the type `unsigned int`. If we cast it to `signed` (which is a shorthand for `signed int`, which is a long-hand for just `int`) we then invoke an implementation-defined conversion that the author of the code is relying upon to produce the most negative `int` value.

Comment: But in the first example, 0x80000000 is not cast at all, but still treated as the minimum integer. How is this possible?

Comment: @herophant If `b[i]` has a type which is 32 bits and signed, then the same conversion takes place implicitly.  Assignment between numeric types performs conversions implicitly, without a cast being required.  The conversion is the same as a cast to the type of the left hand operand.

Answer (score 0):

The constant `0x80000000` has type `unsigned int` because it does not fit into type `int`.  This means conversions may take place when used in expressions with values of type `int`.

First let's take this case:

```
b[i] = 0x80000000;
```

Since `b[i]` has type `int`, the `unsigned int` value is converted in an implementation defined way to `int`.  Assuming a common implementation such as gcc or MSVC on x64, this results in the value -2147483648 being assigned to `b[i]`.  No cast is required here due to how the conversion happens.

Now lets look at the second case:

```
    if ((x > 0 && k > (0x7fffffff - d) / 10) ||
        (x < 0 && k < ((signed)0x80000000 - d) / 10)) {
```

To understand why the cast is necessary, let's see what happens without it:

```
    if ((x > 0 && k > (0x7fffffff - d) / 10) ||
        (x < 0 && k < (0x80000000 - d) / 10)) {
```

First we have `0x80000000 - d`  Because the first operand is `unsigned int` and the second is `signed int`, the latter is converted to `unsigned int` and the resulting expression has type `unsigned int`.  Since the value of `d` is in the range -9 to 0 subtracting this from 0x80000000 == 2147483648 gives you a range of 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,639, and dividing by 10 gives you a range of 214,748,364 to 214,748,363.  `k` is 0 on the first iteration of the loop, so if `x` is negative then you have `0 < 214,748,363` which is false, causing the function to think there's an overflow and return 0.

By casting 0x80000000 to `signed`, the expression `((signed)0x80000000 - d) / 10` evaluates to a value from -2,147,483,648 to -2,147,483,639, which is what we want to compare `k` with.